# Showing the coins suitable for the strategy in the alarm message as a result of scanning in Pine Script v5

Tags: alert, pine-script

With the request.security command, I scan many coins according to the purchase condition I have determined. The coins that are suitable for my strategy are listed and I can see it with the label tag. For example, coins are listed in the label text as BTC/USDT, XLM/USDT.
However, I would like to see these listed coins as an alarm message. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the {{ticker}} variable in your alert message
This should print the asset linked to your alarm

Comment: my problem is a little different.
I am scanning 40 different coins in one indicator. and I list the coins that meet that condition.
I set the alarm on any graph. For example, I am setting up on BTC/USDT. However, since it scans 40 coins on my scan indicator, it shows string expressions such as XLM/USDT, VRA/USDT for example.

But when I use {{ticker}} it sends me the BTC message as I am on the BTC/USDT chart I am using.
I want it to send the list of coins I scan in the form of XLM, VRA.

Comment: ah got it
Why don't you use the alert() function then?
You'll have to build the string made of the screened coins and pass it to the alert() function I think